# sumproduct in different columns between dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to sum between two dates across columns.  If I had a start date input in `Sheet1!F1` and an end date input in `Sheet1!F2` and I needed to multiply `column B` times `column E`.

I can do `sumproduct(Sheet1!B2:B14,Sheet1!E2:E14)` which would result in 48 based on the example table below.  However, I need to include date parameters so I could choose between dates 2/1/15 and 6/1/15 which should result in 20.

```
A       B       C       D       E
Date    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
1/1/2015    1      2       3    4
2/1/2015    1      2       3    4
3/1/2015    1      2       3    4
4/1/2015    1      2       3    4
5/1/2015    1      2       3    4
6/1/2015    1      2       3    4
7/1/2015    1      2       3    4
8/1/2015    1      2       3    4
9/1/2015    1      2       3    4
10/1/2015   1      2       3    4
11/1/2015   1      2       3    4
12/1/2015   1      2       3    4
```

Comment: Didn't I answer this with your last question?

Comment: That one was very similar but different enough where I couldn't deduce how to multiply values from different columns to get a total product as it was also a sumif but thank you!!!

Comment: My bad sorry thought you were back to summing the column.  Missed the whole product part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A2:A14>=Sheet1!F1)*(Sheet1!A2:A14<=Sheet1!F2)*Sheet1!B2:B14*Sheet1!E2:E14)
```

[image]